# Make a user active/inactive PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to build an admin login section to a website where a user can login and edit users/products. I want to be able to make users and products active/inactive rather than deleting them from the database.

I understand I can use tinyint(1) for the true or false values (active or inactive). In my database I have a "isactive" field with the data type tinyint(1) and have set the default value to 1. (Hoping this will mean true or active)

At the top of my edit user form I have the below code:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$_SESSION['editId'] = $_GET['id'];
$status = $_GET['isactive']; 
} else {
$_SESSION['editId'] = 0;    
}
```

my function to edit the user is this:

```
function db_updateUser($user, $id, $connection) {

foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;                         
}   
$sql = "UPDATE  tbl_users SET name='$name', username='$username',password='$password', email='$email', level='$level', isactive='$isactive' WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);  
$numRows = mysqli_affected_rows($connection);
if ($numRows >= 1) {
    return true;    //user updated
} else {
    return false;   //user not updated
}   
}
```

The form select looks like this:

```
<label>Active : </label>
<select name="status">
<option value="Active" <?php if ($status=="Active" || !isset($status)) echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Active</option>
<option value="Inactive" <?php if ($status=="Inactive") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Inactive</option>
</select>
```

I get an error "Undefined index: isactive"

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very greatful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
<select name="status">
```

You should be using

```
$_POST['status'];
```

because that's the name that particular form field is being submitted as.

As well, don't use that foreach() loop to recreate `extract()`. It's extremely poor programming practice, and also highly insecure. Consider the case where someone hacks up a submission to your script and submits `_POST = foo`. Now your $_POST array is GONE.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I have now used '$status = $_POST['status'];' But i still get the warning Undefined index: status...

Comment: If your form is using `method="get"` and you're using `$status = $_POST['status'];` then yes, it will report it as being undefined. @PhilPountney